# PHP $REQUEST explanation

Tags: php, request

In the following line of code the url is being stored in a variable $p_url. My question is on the "pgid" inside of the $_REQUEST method. Is that referencing a variable somewhere else in the script or could the "pgid" be swapped out for any string and still represent the url entered?

```
$p_url = $_REQUEST["pgid"];

$p_url_arr = explode("/", $p_url);

$p = $p_url_arr[0];
$p1 = @$p_url_arr[1]; 
$p2 = @$p_url_arr[1];
$p3 = @$p_url_arr[2];
$p4 = @$p_url_arr[3];
$p5 = @$p_url_arr[4];
$p6 = @$p_url_arr[5];
$p7 = @$p_url_arr[6];
$p8 = @$p_url_arr[7];
$p9 = @$p_url_arr[8];
$p10 = @$p_url_arr[9];
$p11 = @$p_url_arr[10];
$p12 = @$p_url_arr[11];
```

Comment: $_REQUEST is a combination of $_POST and $_GET, so it's data coming from the page request: `pgid` is the name of either a $_GET argument from the page URL, or a $_POST form field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP.net:

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

As Mark said above, I would check the page request. Also you could do:

```
<?php 
   echo "GET:";
   var_dump($_GET);
   echo "Post:";
   var_dump($_POST);
   echo "Cookies:";
   var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Typically variables that can't be changed are those outside of your reach (third-party site,server variables, etc).